# What is the python for Java's BigDecimal?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, currency

In Java, when we program money it is recommended to use the class BigDecimal for money. Is there something similar in python? I would like something object-oriented that can have a currency and an exchange rate, has that been done?

I store money as integers of cents (I think) and multiply with 100 to get dollars but I also have foreign currency so listing listing ordered by price becomes inconvenient when articles have different currencies and even are listed as price per hour or per item. So ideally I would like a class for money in python that has exchange rate, currency and what type of pricing it is, if the pricing is per hour or per item.

So I suppose I'm looking for a `price`class and not a `money`class, is there such a thing already? The gae I'm programming at doesn't have decimal data type so I can use an integer representing just the fraction or invent something like an own decimal representation where I implement it.

Comment: ordering by price in different currencies is going to be very hard.  Individual currencies fluctuate in relation to each other, which means you can't sort that sort of value from the datastore as it would always be wrong.

Comment: @TimHoffman Does it work if you sort everything by the amount of gold you can buy? Or are you saying that values fluctuate too frequently?

Comment: currency isn't like time and timezones ;-) OP said "but I also have foreign currency so listing ordered by price becomes inconvenient when articles have different currencies "  in this situation the OP doesn't have a base currency (I assume) upon to make a consistent comparison.  If one items base value is AU $100 and another item's base value US $100, then at the moment with both hovering around parity from one day to the next the order will be different.   Any base currency would work $US for instance, sort by a base currency and display in local currency, then sorting would work.

Comment: There are two things being mixed here. One is a value and a unit, like 42 and $, which you need to do yourself. Then, you don't want floating-point errors (where the result of large_value +  very_small_value can be equal to large_value) and conversion errors (0.1 not being representable in binary) but really arbitrary precision and decimal numbers. Python's integer type already has arbitrary precision, so you could use it to construct a fixed-point representation for your prices. Looking at the decimal module is a good idea too, but it doesn't have arbitrary precision again.

Comment: @TimHoffman Yes, the solution I was thinking of is keeping a matrix of Exchange rates in memory to convert all prices to the same currency. But then for maximal flexibility prices are also sometimes quoted in unites lite per Square meter or per Pound so it's like you say going to get tricky.

Comment: and won't perform if you have lots of items. It also means you can't use datastore indexes to sort.  IN which case you are probably better off doing the sort at the client end using javascript.

Comment: "I store money as integers of cents (I think) and multiply with 100 to get dollars" - I guess it was rather supposed to be: (..) and DIVIDE by 100 to get dollars ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [java.math.BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in Java's equivalent is [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) in Python. You can even go through the [documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0327/) for more. [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/) is a pure-Python library for multi-precision floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Getting 404 on Python decimal library.

Comment: Not an equivalent! Python's Decimal loses its precision after any math operation.