# How can a org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal stored in an avro file be converted to a python type?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to interpret a **Avro** record stored by **Debezium** in **Kafka**, using **Python**

```
           {
              "name": "id",
              "type": {
                "type": "bytes",
                "scale": 0,
                "precision": 64,
                "connect.version": 1,
                "connect.parameters": {
                  "scale": "0"
                },
                "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
                "logicalType": "decimal"
              }
            }
```

I am not sure to which Python 3 primitive type this corresponds to. How can this value be deserialised?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal` is base64 encoded byte representation of unscaled integer. In order to convert this value to `Decimal`, you need to decode base64 string to bytes, obtain integer and then scale it by `parameters.scale` value.

This schema:

```
{
  "type": "bytes",
  "name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
  "version": 1,
  "parameters": {
    "scale": "9",
    "connect.decimal.precision": "38"
  },
  "field": "amount"
}
```

Can be converted with this following snippet (try it on [Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/6b64fec9-afaf-4504-a0e6-0b57217cd508/?i=true)):

```
ctx = decimal.Context()
ctx.prec = 38  # connect.decimal.precision = 38
result = ctx.create_decimal(
    int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode("GZ6ZFQvYpA=="), byteorder='big')
) / 10 ** 9  # scale = 9
```

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote this more than once - it's up to the point, and does the trick perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Decimal.java

```
public static byte[] fromLogical(Schema schema, BigDecimal value) {
    if (value.scale() != scale(schema))
        throw new DataException("BigDecimal has mismatching scale value for given Decimal schema");
    return value.unscaledValue().toByteArray();
}
```

As you can see it uses BigDecimal and that is equivalent to `Decimal` in python

[What is the python for Java's BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996527/what-is-the-python-for-javas-bigdecimal)

So you should be looking for Decimal in this case.

**Part 2 - Deserialization**

About the deserialization, I need feedback to update the answer. How do you do it for other fields as of now?

Comment: How to convert org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal in java ? Current value looks something like "FGk=" I want to convert this into a readable numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

When I use other answer for negative number, it give wrong result.
for example -20.62 numeric is converted to "+CA=" by debezium to kafka

I find the solution from below link and I change like this.

```
import decimal
import base64
def big_decimal_to_decimal(big_decimal, scale, precision):
    bytes_val = base64.decodebytes(big_decimal.encode())
    bval = "".join("{0:08b}".format(c) for c in bytes_val)
    intval = int(bval, 2)
    if bytes_val[0] & 0x70 != 0:
        intval -= int('1' + '00' * len(bytes_val), 16)
    return intval/(10**scale)
```

link : [Decode base64 encoded byte array to (negative) decimal value (Java to Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885704/decode-base64-encoded-byte-array-to-negative-decimal-value-java-to-python)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31212620)