# converting a base64 decoded string to list in python does not produce same result as in Java array output

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, list, base64

I have a base64 encoded string `pTWlzYwVk74RHlbhrHtYxjlmTpa1KY3LVj3X8o3PHUURfY07Qnk5wFPHP7SHDvoJSaM24DybXt20+ou3evsEmLNQfzsF2A1lfSsG2dIKf5Gmhb1qXVN7C6z1mJIRTWt99ei9A1Ozyc7et2DpKpX0SGIaKPcmf2TomYvt1Q+YWTaabUoue9BgI2VHb3L2f/UdRo5ja6beSeA=` forexample, In `Java` when decoding this base64 decoded I get the correct result but in python different result. Here is the code I used.
`python code`

```
decoded = base64.b64decode("pTWlzYwVk74RHlbhrHtYxjlmTpa1KY3LVj3X8o3PHUURfY07Qnk5wFPHP7SHDvoJSaM24DybXt20+ou3evsEmLNQfzsF2A1lfSsG2dIKf5Gmhb1qXVN7C6z1mJIRTWt99ei9A1Ozyc7et2DpKpX0SGIaKPcmf2TomYvt1Q+YWTaabUoue9BgI2VHb3L2f/UdRo5ja6beSeA=")
mylist = list(decoded )
print("mylist", mylist)
```

**output becomes**

```
mylist [165, 53, 165, 205, 140, 21, 147, 190, 17, 30, 86, 225, 172, 123, 88, 198, 57, 102, 78, 150, 181, 41, 141, 203, 86, 61, 215, 242, 141, 207, 29, 69, 17, 125, 141, 59, 66, 121, 57, 192, 83, 199, 63, 180, 135, 14, 250, 9, 73, 163, 54, 224, 60, 155, 94, 221, 180, 250, 139, 183, 122, 251, 4, 152, 179, 80, 127, 59, 5, 216, 13, 101, 125, 43, 6, 217, 210, 10, 127, 145, 166, 133, 189, 106, 93, 83, 123, 11, 172, 245, 152, 146, 17, 77, 107, 125, 245, 232, 189, 3, 83, 179, 201, 206, 222, 183, 96, 233, 42, 149, 244, 72, 98, 26, 40, 247, 38, 127, 100, 232, 153, 139, 237, 213, 15, 152, 89, 54, 154, 109, 74, 46, 123, 208, 96, 35, 101, 71, 111, 114, 246, 127, 245, 29, 70, 142, 99, 107, 166, 222, 73, 224]
```

**and the `Java` side I have used like this**

```
String str = "pTWlzYwVk74RHlbhrHtYxjlmTpa1KY3LVj3X8o3PHUURfY07Qnk5wFPHP7SHDvoJSaM24DybXt20+ou3evsEmLNQfzsF2A1lfSsG2dIKf5Gmhb1qXVN7C6z1mJIRTWt99ei9A1Ozyc7et2DpKpX0SGIaKPcmf2TomYvt1Q+YWTaabUoue9BgI2VHb3L2f/UdRo5ja6beSeA="
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println("myarray: "+Arrays.toString(decoded));
```

**and output becomes**

```
[-91, 53, -91, -51, -116, 21, -109, -66, 17, 30, 86, -31, -84, 123, 88, -58, 57, 102, 78, -106, -75, 41, -115, -53, 86, 61, -41, -14, -115, -49, 29, 69, 17, 125, -115, 59, 66, 121, 57, -64, 83, -57, 63, -76, -121, 14, -6, 9, 73, -93, 54, -32, 60, -101, 94, -35, -76, -6, -117, -73, 122, -5, 4, -104, -77, 80, 127, 59, 5, -40, 13, 101, 125, 43, 6, -39, -46, 10, 127, -111, -90, -123, -67, 106, 93, 83, 123, 11, -84, -11, -104, -110, 17, 77, 107, 125, -11, -24, -67, 3, 83, -77, -55, -50, -34, -73, 96, -23, 42, -107, -12, 72, 98, 26, 40, -9, 38, 127, 100, -24, -103, -117, -19, -43, 15, -104, 89, 54, -102, 109, 74, 46, 123, -48, 96, 35, 101, 71, 111, 114, -10, 127, -11, 29, 70, -114, 99, 107, -90, -34, 73, -32]
```

in **comparison**, the positive values of the two output is same but negatives the python version is outputting different result. **why is that?** what am I doing wrong? I saw a similar issue on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885704/decode-base64-encoded-byte-array-to-negative-decimal-value-java-to-python) on **stackoverflow**, but Unfortunately does not resolve my issue.

Comment: Looks to me like a case of signed vs. unsigned considering that, looking at the first element of the resulting arrays -91 is the 2's complement of 165.

Comment: Yes, so go through and `& 0xFF`

Comment: @g00se why python does need `& 0xFF` while java not?

Comment: it's the other way around. Java needs the `& 0xFF` treament. Not sure about Python's numeric types but all Java's (apart from `char`) are *signed* so you need to 'unsign' them. You'll have type `byte` here, in an array from your decode

Comment: @g00se I am still unable to solve this in python

Comment: What is there to 'solve'?

Comment: to get the list in signed format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235825/discussion-between-g00se-and-hanan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those result are same.

In java `byte` is signed type, so values bigger than 127 are considered negatives.

Apparently in python `byte` is unsigned.

Comment: so how can I get the exact numbers here? I mean the signed numbers using python

Comment: I don't know. There are couple of solution here https://blog.michaelyin.info/convert-8bit-byte-to-signed-int/. But you better ask new question, because I don't speak python.

Comment: thanks this was the exact solution I was thinking of.